# CamelContextAware has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have this error

> org/apache/camel/CamelContextAware has been compiled by a more recent
> version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of
> the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

When I am trying to compile maven in a Spring Boot Camel application.
There is no trace of explanation of this error in documentation, the only thing I found is a [very short javadoc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.12.0/org/apache/camel/CamelContextAware.html). Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was here

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-test-spring-junit5</artifactId>
        <version>3.15.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Setting version at `3.12.0` solved for me.